# Rewriting Controller code as Model Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, models, laravel-blade

I'm trying to convert code I wrote for my Controller to work as a model so that I can pull the information into a Blade.

Basically I'm taking random percents from a table in my database labeled "margins" and multiplying it by the cost of multiple items. I then need to do something like

```
@foreach($item_cost as $ic)
Item Name: {{ $ic->name }} Cost: {{ $ic->cost }}
@endforeach
```

where it pulls the item name from the "items" table and then multiplies a base cost by the margin in the "margins" table.

```
public function drug_margins()
{
    $locations = Locations::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    $drugs = Drugs::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    $margins = Margins::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    $add = $locations->margin*$drugs->base_value*$margins->percent;
    $cost = $add+$drugs->base_value;
    return "<h2>Trismegistus Drug Cost Randomizer</h2><br>Drug Name: " . $drugs->name . "<br>" . "Location: " . $locations->name . "<br>" . "Location Margin: " . $locations->margin . "<br>" . "Margin: " . $margins->percent . "<br>" . "Drug Base Value: " . $drugs->base_value . "<br>" . "New Cost: " . $cost . "<br>";
}
```

If this isn't make sense please let me know so I can clarify.

TIA!

I've tried using the information from the first answer but it's not working 100%. The cost is changing accordingly however the "Drug Name" is staying the same no matter what.

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Drugs extends Model
{
//
protected $table = 'drugs';
public function user_data()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('user_data', 'TableID', 'id');
}

public function getCostAttribute()
{
    $locations = Locations::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    $drugs = Drugs::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    // $drugs = Drugs::find(1)->get()->first();
    $margins = Margins::inRandomOrder()->get()->first();
    $add = $locations->margin*$drugs->base_value*$margins->percent;
    $cost = $add+$drugs->base_value;
    //$cost = array('name' => $drugs->name, 'base_value' => $drugs-    >base_value, 'cst' => $cst); // Presents array but can't get it to work as variables in view
    return $cost;
    } 
}
```

and here is my Controller:

```
    public function drug_margins()
{
    $drugs = Drugs::inRandomOrder()->first();
    $drugs = $drugs->cost;
    dd($drugs); // Testing Phase
    // return view('test.test', compact('drugs'));
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong. Again the drug costs are changing properly now but the drug name stays as the first drug which is Aspirin.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in the model as:

```
public function getCostAttribute()
{
    // write your logic here
    return $cost;
}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
{{ $model->cost  }}
```

Comment: That looks cool now will I be able to do a foreach on that to pull back all the costs in the table?

Comment: Ok that partially worked but I'm not pulling back all the information that's changing. For some reason the Drug Name isn't changing.